# Changing the MAC Address in Vista - Broadcom adapter

Tags: windows-vista, networking, mac-address, broadcom

Is there a way that we could override the default mac address / set a new mac address on a Vista machine for a Broadcom adapter ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can't say for your particular case, but I've used one of the two tools mentioned [over here](http://ayaz.wordpress.com/2007/11/24/spoofing-mac-address-i-be-very-bad/) to spoof/change the MAC address of the Ethernet adapter on Windows Vista before.

Answer (score 1):

Probably not - this is easy in Linux though :)