# Protect my java application from being copied (only for one pc)

Tags: java, windows, security, desktop-application, copy-protection

How do I stop someone from copying  the application i am making in java in an other pc ? i want to sell it only for one pc

I am not selling it on the internet , is there any way to do that by the disk SN or using USB Flash disk SN of the client as a key for the app ?

I am using mysql as back-end for my application and the platform is Windows.

Is there a way to provide this security ?

Comment: Have you searched the web for this already? When I search I find a number of options, with the caveat that without a lot of effort/money you'll stop only the weakest of attempts. Is it really worth it?

Comment: Did you really create the next incarnation of MS-Word? Perhaps you should concentrate not so much on selling the software, but on selling the value of your services associated with the software.

Comment: Well, the way Microsoft handles this is by issuing a unique CD key to each purchase/license, and then registering each installation (identified by a "system ID") against a validation server on the internet. But my suggestion to you would be to first worry about making a great product that's worth stealing, and then worry about how to implement copy protection.  Also, if you're distributing MySQL with your software, I hope you've reviewed _their_ license.

Comment: I feel that might be difficult because thousands of developers dedicated _lot_ of their time to specifically make portability possible. So, they might have ignored this aspect completely.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the PC is connected to the internet, you could read the PC MAC address when starting the application and send a request to your server to check if that MAC address is authorised.

But that means that every time the user changes his PC you need to update your records.

Comment: And the MAC could be spoofed _just like that_

Comment: @goldenparrot If someone really wants to find his way, he will.

Comment: @assylias sir about the mac address , how i can test it and give the client pc an autorisation to start working ?

Comment: @user1417996 Have a look at [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33960/how-do-you-get-the-ethernet-address-using-java) to find the MAC address. And have a look at [this other one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/307932/changing-the-mac-address-in-vista-broadcom-adapter) as to how your users could change their mac address.

Comment: @assylias sir who going to buy my application they don't know how to change the MAC adresse due to that i want to do it , Thank you sir

Comment: @assylias can i do that with the disk Serial Number ??

Comment: @user1417996 Put it simply, licensing restrictions is a never-ending fight. You better be willing to put in an endless effort into it - especially if your product is any good.

Comment: @user1417996 Have a look [at this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5482947/how-to-get-hard-disk-serial-number-using-java).

Comment: @Mysticial Pffffff I want my 15 ;-)

Comment: @assylias: looks like you got it, congrats!

Answer (score 0):

I reckon the only way you'll be able to achieve this level of control is if you move your application into a cloud-based service such as Amazon Web Services. That way, your clients have to subscribe to gain access to your application, and you can disable access if payment stops.